# Compare a key in an Object in an Array with another key in an Object in Another array and merge them together if the values are equal

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-merge

I have two arrays:

```
var array1 = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Name 1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Name 2' },
  ...
];

var array2 = [
  { someId: '1', someField: 'Some Value 1' },
  { someId: '2', someField: 'Some Value 2' },
  ...
];
```

`array1` will have objects coming from the backend in batches of 30. As soon as I get a batch, I extract the `Ids` from this array, and call another API to get the `array2` for those ids.

Eventually, I want an array like this:

```
var array3 = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Name 1', someOtherField: 'Some Value 1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Name 2', someOtherField: 'Some Value 2' },
  ...
];
```

I could do something like this:

```
ids = array1.map(item => item.id);
var resultingArray = array2.map((item, index) => {
  return array1[index].someOtherField = item.someField
});
```

But since I have the items of array1 in batches, it would be hard to maintain the indexes correctly.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine both arrays, and use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with some [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to get both `id` and `someId` as `id`, and store everything on a dictionary (POJO). We get an array by using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) on the dictionary:

```js
const array1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'Name 1' }, { id: 2, name: 'Name 2' }];

const array2 = [{ someId: '1', someField: 'Some Value 1' }, { someId: '2', someField: 'Some Value 2' }];

const result = Object.values(
  // combine both arrays
  [...array1, ...array2]
  // use destructuring to get someId/id as id, and the rest of objects' props
  .reduce((r, { someId, id = someId, ...rest }) => ({
    ...r, // spread the previous accumulator
    [id]: { id, ...r[id], ...rest } // add the current object, with the id, props, and previous data if any
  }), {})
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Perfect. Let me try this out. :)

Answer (score 2):

Build up a lookup table for the `array2` ids:

```
 const ids = new Map(array2.map(el => [el.id, /*to*/ el]));
```

Then adding the data from `array1` is as easy as:

```
 for(const el of array2) {
   if(ids.has(el.id)) {
      // Merge properties
     Object.assign(ids.get(el.id), el);
   } else {
     // Add to Map and array
     array1.push(el);
     ids.set(el.id, el);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to this? I'm pretty new to `Map` and haven't used it before.

Comment: @SiddAjmera I can't tell you more than what the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) contain